# Copy textbox value to a new window

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to copy a html textbox value from one window to another window using php? My syntax can copy textbox value but what it does copy the value from current page and goes to the next page; What i want is a new window will open with all the textbox value; Can you perhaps give me a simple syntax on how to do it; I done a couple of searches online using google but it is quite complicated for me. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So you want to populate a text box on a second page with the value of a text box from the first page?

Comment: yes evan, but what happens is

WINDOW A page1 -> WINDOW A page2

what i want is something like

WINDOW A page 1 -> WINDOW B page 2

is this possible?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by all of this.  If you submit it with a form then just use:
`echo "<textarea>$_FORM['myTextBox']</textarea>";`

Comment: yes thats what i had in my form.

sorry i think i got you confuse.

Lets say user enters a value in a text box and submits it what happens is the values will be populated to the next screen using the same window

What i want is once the user enters a value and submits it a new window will open with the values the user submitted; making it two windows for the user to see

Comment: I still don't understand.  I'm not sure what you are referring to by windows.  Does it open a new browser window or just advances a page or a dig or view on a page?

Comment: browser would be the good word for it thanks for clarifying; so what happens is user enters a value in the textbox and once he hits submit a new browser will open with the those values

Comment: I would make changes to your question reflecting that.

Comment: ok sorry im having a hard time to interpret what i want to do

Comment: If you are still submitting the form then its still in an array and you can populate the textbox with it using echo.  Another way to go would be to use something like jQuery and javascript instead of use server side to handle your UI stuff.

Comment: If you explain what your project is and what it is going to be used for then that would be a great help.

Comment: i see so javascript is the best one to use here i know a few for js but can i review them is it ok if you can give me a simple syntax that works for output i have been trying to figure out?

Comment: sure evan, my projects basically does data encoding for all employee information; I have come up to this part were you need to enter dependents, since all employee have different number of dependents/children; i cant do this with one form (well its possible but that would create more textboxes for the user to fill in which is hassle for them) thats why i was planning to copy the first last and middle name into  another form (which is the new browser i was asking earlier). if you have something in mind that would make it easier for me that would be helpful

Comment: So how are you displaying that second window?

Comment: You really need to show some code in your question and modify it to reflect the information you've given me in your comments.

Comment: one the first form there will have two buttons one for adding a dependent and the other for saving the values in that window

Comment: something like this http://www.plus2net.com/html_tutorial/submit-two.php but instead of just printing the value it should have it on a textbox just saw this link while i was asking you earlier

Comment: So instead of printing the value just do echo `<textbox>$_FORM['value']</textbox>`

Comment: i see ill give it a try now thanks a lot Evan you have been helpful ill notify you about the progress of this one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read all the comments above and if i understand right the following could be an answer, but you have to use php with javascript, or use an a-Tag(also with use of javascript code) to get to success:

if you push your submit button, do one of the following things:

1. open a new window with a constructed url of your values of the form:

   ```
   //construct your string
   //this is only a finished example
   var str = 'site.php?paramName1=thisIsTheValue&paramName2=thisIsValue2';

   window.open(str,'mywindow','width=400,height=200');
   ```
2. change the href-Attribute of an a tag with javascript. href should be like this:
   `href="site.php?paramName1=thisIsTheValue&paramName2=thisIsValue2"`
   (this only works if the user hits ctrl on its keybord or opens it in a new tab/window. It does not immediately show you a new window if you hit submit)

Your PHP code is on both options the same (site.php):

```
<?php
//do something
echo $_GET['paramName1'];
//do something
?>
```

The php code above is vulnerable for security attacks so use functions like `htmlspecialchars()` or others to achieve secure code.